# iOS not playing sound

Tags: ios

So, I am making a game and it is almost done, however, the problem I am having is that when the player comes in contact with the bomb, it just kills the player and does not play any sound effect. It plays the sound effect when collecting items though. The collection for the items are set up the exact same. When I collect an item, it plays the sound effect, when I hit a bomb, it doest play anything. Just silence. Please help!

```
 if firstBody.node?.name == "Player" && secondBody.node?.name == "Bomb" {
        if sound == true {
            self.run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Bomb.mp3", waitForCompletion: false))
        }
        firstBody.node?.removeFromParent()
        secondBody.node?.removeFromParent()

        self.scene?.isPaused = true

        playerDied()
    }
```

Comment: Can you show more of your code? For instance, what is "sound"?

Comment: Sound is just a universal variable that I created. It Identifies if the user pressed the "Sound Off Button"

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to call the PlayerDied() function inside the override update function